# Performance question: Fastest way to convert hexadecimal char to its number value in Java?

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I want to convert from char representing a hexadecimal value (in upper or lower case) to byte, like

```
'0'->0, '1' -> 1, 'A' -> 10, 'a' -> 10, 'f' -> 15 etc...
```

I will be calling this method extremely often, so performance is important. Is there a faster way than to use a pre-initialized `HashMap<Character,Byte>` to get the value from?

**Answer**

It seems like <s>it's a tossup between using a switch-case and Jon Skeet's direct computing solution - the switch-case solution seems to edge out ever so slightly, though.</s> Greg's array method wins out. Here are the performance results (in ms) for 200,000,000 runs of the various methods:

```
Character.getNumericValue:
8360

Character.digit:
8453

HashMap<Character,Byte>:
15109

Greg's Array Method:
6656

JonSkeet's Direct Method:
7344

Switch:
7281
```

Thanks guys!

**Benchmark method code**

Here ya go, JonSkeet, you old competitor. ;-)

```
public class ScratchPad {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_RUNS = 200000000;

    static byte res;

    static HashMap<Character, Byte> map = new HashMap<Character, Byte>() {{
        put( Character.valueOf( '0' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )0 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '1' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )1 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '2' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )2 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '3' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )3 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '4' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )4 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '5' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )5 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '6' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )6 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '7' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )7 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '8' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )8 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( '9' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )9 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'a' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )10 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'b' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )11 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'c' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )12 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'd' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )13 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'e' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )14 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'f' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )15 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'A' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )10 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'B' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )11 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'C' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )12 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'D' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )13 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'E' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )14 ));
        put( Character.valueOf( 'F' ), Byte.valueOf( (byte )15 ));
    }};
    static int[] charValues = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 10, 11, 12, 13,14,15,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
                    -1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10, 11, 12, 13,14,15};
    static char[] cs = new char[]{'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f','A','B','C','D','E','F'};

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            res = getNumericValue( i );
        }
        System.out.println( "Character.getNumericValue:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            res = getDigit( i );
        }
        System.out.println( "Character.digit:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            try {
                res = getValueFromArray( i );
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Array:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            res = getValueFromHashMap( i );
        }
        System.out.println( "HashMap<Character,Byte>:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            char c = cs[i%cs.length];
            res = getValueFromComputeMethod( c );        
        }
        System.out.println( "JonSkeet's Direct Method:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++ ) {
            res = getValueFromSwitch( i );

        }
        System.out.println( "Switch:" );
        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis()-time );
    }

    private static byte getValueFromSwitch( int i ) {
        byte res;
        char ch = cs[i%cs.length];
        switch( ch ) {
            case '0':
                res = 0;
                break;
            case '1':
                res = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                res = 2;
                break;
            case '3':
                res = 3;
                break;
            case '4':
                res = 4;
                break;
            case '5':
                res = 5;
                break;
            case '6':
                res = 6;
                break;
            case '7':
                res = 7;
                break;
            case '8':
                res = 8;
                break;
            case '9':
                res = 9;
                break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
                res = 10;
                break;
            case 'b':
            case 'B':    
                res = 11;
                break;
            case 'c':
            case 'C':    
                res = 12;
                break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':    
                res = 13;
                break;
            case 'e':
            case 'E':    
                res = 14;
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'F':    
                res = 15;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("unknown hex character: " + ch );
        }
        return res;
    }

    private static byte getValueFromComputeMethod( char c ) {
        byte result = 0;
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            result =  (byte)(c - '0');
        }
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        {
            result = (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);
        }
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
        {
            result =  (byte)(c - 'A' + 10);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static byte getValueFromHashMap( int i ) {
        return map.get( Character.valueOf( cs[i%cs.length] ) ).byteValue();
    }

    private static byte getValueFromArray( int i ) {
        char c = cs[i%cs.length];
        if (c < '0' || c > 'f') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        byte result = (byte)charValues[c-'0'];
        if (res < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static byte getDigit( int i ) {
        return (byte)Character.digit( cs[i%cs.length], 16 );
    }

    private static byte getNumericValue( int i ) {
        return (byte)Character.getNumericValue( cs[i%cs.length] );
    }

}
```

Comment: Were there any performance problems using the library functions? If there are none, Character.digit(char, radix) should be sufficient.

Comment: One thing to consider with this benchmark is that the array will work well *while it's in cache* - which is great if you're doing lots of iterations in one go. If you have to wait for a the array to be fetched from main memory, however, a purely computational approach will be quicker.

Comment: In other words: "it depends" :)

Comment: Epaga: Could you publish your benchmark code? I've an idea to tweak Greg's code a little which might make it slightly faster. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel by writing my own benchmark though :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A preinitialised array would be faster than a HashMap. Something like this:

```
int CharValues['f'-'0'+1] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, -1, -1, ... -1, 10, 11, 12, ...};

if (c < '0' || c > 'f') {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
int n = CharValues[c-'0'];
if (n < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
// n contains the digit value
```

You should benchmark this method against other methods (such as [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221001/performance-question-fastest-way-to-convert-hexadecimal-char-to-its-number-valu#221012) direct method) to determine which will be the fastest for your application.

Comment: first check for range should be removed: it only slows down the conversion; array will check it's boundaries itself; the exception will be different, but we're trading everything for speed, don't we?

Comment: That's a good idea, and if you're concerned about the exception type you could catch the array exception and throw a different one.

Answer (score 14):

A hash table would be relatively slow. This is pretty quick:

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
{
    return c - '0';
}
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
{
    return c - 'a' + 10;
}
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
{
    return c - 'A' + 10;
}
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Another option would be to try a switch/case statement. An array might be okay if it's in cache, but a miss could be expensive.

Comment: What I say three times is true.

Comment: Ick, no idea what happened there. That's what I get for posting from a mobile. Will edit.

Comment: There are a few variations of this, and generally this would be fastest, short of a 256-byte look-up table a la Pro

Answer (score 5):

I don't recall seeing this method before, but Mikko Rantanen pointed this equation out in a comment on the question, [Code golf - hex to (raw) binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795027/code-golf-hex-to-raw-binary-conversion)

```
(char | 32) % 39 - 9
```

I don't know what it would benchmark as (perhaps someone can add it to the benchmark above and run it, but I'm guessing the % kills the performance) - but it's a neat, simple one-liner for single character hexadecimal to decimal conversion.  Handles 0-9, A-F, a-f.

Comment: The modulo does kill the performance. However, this would be by far the fastest solution if you are compiling the java to an executable because on many modern computers, the RAM access speed is a bit slower, making lookup tables really degrade performance if you are accessing the ram to get the hexadecimal you are working with.

Answer (score 4):

```
int CharValues[256] = 
{
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,
16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16,16
}

int n = CharValues[c];

if (n == 16)
 throw new IllegalArgumentException();

// n contains the digit value
```

Comment: I believe your array is wrong - the '0' should start at location 0x30, you have it starting at 0x2D.  'A' should start at 0x41, you have it starting at 0x40, and you don't support lower case characters ('a' starts at 0x61)

Comment: agreed - I think I've got it right now... but would appreciate you checking as it's making me dizzy looking at it

Answer (score 3):

Using an array should be fastest.

An array could be of size 16, 16^2, 16^3, 16^4 etc..

Converting the number in larger groups than one would give a performance increase.

There will be a sweet spot where it is most worthwhile, possibly 4 digits (64k table).

Comment: Why do you say it "should" be fastest? It all depends on the balance of memory access vs computation. That will partly depend on caching, the memory architecture of your particular machine etc. There's a lot to consider :)

Comment: Yes - but computation involves accessing memory for the instructions.

In the case of one character it will be close, as benchmarked but even in this case an array lookup is only one read.

In the general case, doing blocks of 4 in an array lookup should be much faster.

Your points noted however!

Comment: Using a binary search pattern, that would take 16 iterations with a 64k length 128kb table, making it less efficient than Adam Davis's solution on most modern hardware.

Answer (score 3):

Dude, I'm microcontroller programmer and in this tiny world, speed really matters. The fastest way to convert an 'ASCII' digit to byte (from 'A' to 0x0A) is using this small piece of code

```
c|=0x20;
return c<='9'? c+0xD0 : c+0xA9;
```

The magic of this command is simple, if you look the ascii table you'll find numbers starting with 0x3_, and letters at columns 0x4_ and 0x6_ respectively. 
1) if you "or" the incoming char (variable "c") with 0x20, you'll be never changing numbers... but for letters you'll be converting uppercase to lowercase. Since we are looking for only A..F(a..f) values... I don't care others.
2) now the magic. To avoid subtractions, I use additive operators. the 0xD0 is the same of -0x30, and 0xA9 is the same of -'a'+10;

the branch instruction generated by the comparison is pretty simple and didn't take the overhead of table lookups and neither "mod" or other operators!

Enjoy...

Comment: This doesn't work for Java's 16-bit chars, but I suppose it could be adapted.

Answer (score 2):

Character.getNumericValue(char) is another way:

```
char c = 'a';
System.out.println(c + "->" + Character.getNumericValue(c));
```

Prints 'a->10' like you want for instance. Someone else would have to comment on the efficiency of a static metod call vs a HashMap lookup, or you could check it out for yourself. It seems cleaner/more readable to me though.

Answer (score 2):

simple, but slow:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(String.ValueOf(c), 16);
```

faster:

```
int i = Character.digit(c, 16);
```

I wont use any special code for "performance issues". If you really often use this, the JIT will create compiled code and execution will become fast. Keep your code clean. You may have a try and write a performace test comparing the execution time from the code above and any special implementation - i bet you wont get significant improvements.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can beat a direct array lookup.

```
static final int[] precalc = new int['f'+1];
static {
    for (char c='0'; c<='9'; c++) precalc[c] = c-'0';
    for (char c='A'; c<='F'; c++) precalc[c] = c-'A';
    for (char c='a'; c<='f'; c++) precalc[c] = c-'a';
}

System.out.println(precalc['f']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my tweaked version of Greg's code. On my box it's *marginally* faster - but probably within the noise. It avoids the lower bound check, and doesn't need to do any subtraction. Creating a 64K array and avoiding *either* bound check appeared to slow things down - but again, with timing like this it's virtually impossible to be sure what's real and what's noise.

```
public class HexParser
{
    private static final byte VALUES = new int['f'];

    // Easier to get right for bozos like me (Jon) than
    // a hard-coded array :)
    static
    {
        for (int i=0; i < VALUES.length; i++)
        {
            VALUES[i] = (byte) -1;
        }
        for (int i='0'; i <= '9'; i++)
        {
            VALUES[i] = (byte) i-'0';
        }
        for (int i='A'; i <= 'F'; i++)
        {
            VALUES[i] = (byte) (i-'A'+10);
        }
        for (int i='a'; i <= 'f'; i++)
        {
            VALUES[i] = (byte) (i-'a'+10);
        }
    }

    public static byte parseHexChar(char c)
    {
        if (c > 'f')
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        byte ret = VALUES[c];
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It worth noting that you are realing timing the % operation in most of your tests. This operation takes about the same amount of time as some of the other options.

```
private static byte lookUpTest(int i) {
    return (byte) cs[i%cs.length];
}
```

Comment: totally agreed. the % is a very slow operation.

Answer (score 1):

A table of 16-bit values where you could look up two digits at a time should be quicker than the 8-bit-value arrays suggested in other answers. You would be iterating the data twice as quickly, accessing the array half as often, and accessing shorts instead of bytes, all of which gives the CPU less to do and more to do it with.

The 8-bit values would be precomputed as `x[Integer.toHexString(i).charAt[0]] = i` for `0 <= i < 256`. Then you would just lookup `x[c]` for each char `c` in the hex string. You would probably want to duplicate the entries for both upper-case and lower-case variants of each hex value.

A table of 32-bit values should be even quicker, depending on how much space you can afford.

Answer (score 1):

According to my timings the following outperforms Jon Skeet's already pretty efficient method.

The idea is to take advantage of the test on range `'A'..'F'` to also discard one of the ranges `'0'..'9'` or `'a'..'f'`.

```
public static int hex2Dig2(char c) {
    if (c < 'A') {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            return c - '0';
    } else if (c > 'F') {
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
            return c - 'a' + 10;
    } else {
        return c - 'A' + 10;
    }
    return -1; // or throw exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this method?

```java
static byte unhex(int i) {
    return (byte) (i >= 0x30 && i <= 0x39
                   ? 0x30 - i
                   : i >= 0x41 && i <= 0x46
                   ? i - 0x37
                   : i - 0x57);
}
```