# Base64 encoding of a SHA256 string

Tags: c#, base64, sha256

I am currently doing a program in C #. When I tried to pass my string from sha256 to base64, I realized that it was not being encoded correctly.

For instance, given the sha256

```
cd69ef0284bba33bc0b320e6479c2da2d411a5e46af060d8639f0e0bfc24f26d
```

My code produces

```
Y2Q0Q2OUVGMDI4NEJCQTMzQkMwQjMyMEU2NDc5QzJEQTJENDExQTVFNDZBRjA2MEQ4NjM5RjBFMEJGQzI0RjI2RA==
```

What I'm expecting to get is

```
zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0
```

Why are encoded strings so different and what am I missing?

This is the code I am using

```
string t1 ="cd69ef0284bba33bc0b320e6479c2da2d411a5e46af060d8639f0e0bfc24f26d";
var t2= System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(t1);                                
string t3= System.Convert.ToBase64String(t2);
```

Comment: Where is the expected value of `zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0` coming from? If you show us your source code, it will help.

Comment: @Griswald_911 I am getting this 'Y2Q0Q2OUVGMDI4NEJCQTMzQkMwQjMyMEU2NDc5QzJEQTJENDExQTVFNDZBRjA2MEQ4NjM5RjBFMEJGQzI0RjI2RA==' from my code I expect to get this 'zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0
'

Comment: @Pedro how did you get the value `zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0`? and what are you trying to compute in the first place?

Comment: His expected result can be reversed:  `BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String("zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0" + "=")).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant()`  and you will get his input SHA256 value. Thus @daisy-shipton guess is probably correct how he got his expected result.

Comment: @Pedro: See Daisy's answer below. As she explains, you really want to just take the raw binary from the SHA-256 hash and pass it directly to the `System.Convert.ToBase64String` method that accepts a `byte[]`. By the time you get to the string value of `t1`, you have already gone too far.  In other words, it is best to encode the hash as base64, and not a string or hex representation of that hash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of SHA-256 is a binary value, typically expressed as a byte array. You've converted that into a hex string, then base64-encoded that hex string.

Instead, you should be base64-encoding the original binary data, without converting it to hex first.

If you *have* to go via the hex first, you should parse that back to the original bytes, *then* base64 encode the result:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "cd69ef0284bba33bc0b320e6479c2da2d411a5e46af060d8639f0e0bfc24f26d";
        byte[] data = ParseHex(text);
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(data));
    }

    // Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795027/code-golf-hex-to-raw-binary-conversion/795036#795036
    static byte[] ParseHex(string text)
    {
        Func<char, int> parseNybble = c => (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ? c-'0' : char.ToLower(c)-'a'+10;
        return Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length/2)
            .Select(x => (byte) ((parseNybble(text[x*2]) << 4) | parseNybble(text[x*2+1])))
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

... but it would be better just not to convert the hash into hex to start with.

Comment: I am getting this 'zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0=' but i want this 'zWnvAoS7ozvAsyDmR5wtotQRpeRq8GDYY58OC/wk8m0' you know why I am getting '=' ?

Comment: @Pedro: That's padding for base64. It's correct in terms of regular base64. Some base64 schemes trim it and rely on the length of the text - if that's the case for your situation, you can just use `TrimEnd` to remove any trailing `=` signs.

Answer (score 0):

We can now use '**Base64UrlTextEncoder**' from '**Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities**' in .Net core applications.

What you are looking for is URL safe Base64 string version which is predominantly seen in OAuth(PIKCE) flows.

```
using var alg = SHA256.Create();
using var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("R15iKJ_Kx4r1gX0TMwzCnpkq3Zqcz-h-r00BhshyQ6o"));
var hashBytes = alg.ComputeHashAsync(stream).Result;
Console.WriteLine($"URL safe Base64: {Base64UrlTextEncoder.Encode(hashBytes)}");
```

Some sample outputs:

> **Hex string**: 051627b9015ffdd5672903e226089fda574c825acc5d46e83b02310ef329c04

> **Normal Base64**: UFFie5AV/91WcpA+ImCJ/aV0yCWsxdRug7AjEO8ynAQ=

> **URL safe Base64**: UFFie5AV_91WcpA-ImCJ_aV0yCWsxdRug7AjEO8ynAQ