# How to convert a char from an alphabetical character to a hexadecimal number in Java?

Tags: java, methods, char, hex

How do I convert a char from an alphabetical character to hexadecimal number in Java? If any one knows any built-in methods in Java that does the job or if you have your own method, could you please help?

Also, how would I convert from hex to binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance question: Fastest way to convert hexadecimal char to its number value in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221001/performance-question-fastest-way-to-convert-hexadecimal-char-to-its-number-valu)

Answer (score 31):

You can convert from char to hex string.

```
char ch = 
String hex = String.format("%04x", (int) ch);
```

To read hex and convert to binary you can do

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(text, 16);
String bin = Integer.toString(num, 2);
```

Comment: That `char` has to be cast to an `int` or you'll get an `IllegalFormatConversionException`.

Comment: Well spotted, I forgot it auto-boxes rather than up casting.

Comment: That gives me Cannot cast from char[] to int

Comment: @machado where is the `char []` being used?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < iavailable; i++) {
           readDataToText[i] = (char) readData[i];
          }

where readData is a byte[]

Comment: @Machado and where are you casting a char [] to an int?

Comment: @PeterLawrey inside a Handler(), specifically inside the handleMessage method

Comment: @Machado Sorry, can you show me the code which actually has the error.  I suspect you have more code than you need.

Comment: @Machado e.g. to convert part of a `byte[]` to an `int` you can do `int num = Integer.parseInt(new String(bytes, start, length));` No loops or `char[]` needed.

Answer (score 21):

You could use:

```
Integer.toHexString((int) 'a');
Integer.toBinaryString((int) 'b');
```

Update: hex -> binary conversion:

```
Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt("fa", 16))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [apache commons codec library](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)

Specifically:
http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html