# Java Unicode replacement char with hex code

Tags: java, string, unicode

I need to replace all special unicode chars in a string with an escape char "\" and its hex value.
For example, this string:

```
String test="This is a string with the special è unicode char";
```

Shuld be replaced with:

```
"This is a string with the special \E8 unicode char";
```

where E8 is the hex value of unicode value of char "è".

Comment: ok. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have two problem: how to find "special chars", may I check for each char value if it is >127? And how to get hex value as string.

Comment: 1rst result on google ["convert char to hex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-alphabetical-character-to-hexadecimal-number-in-java)

Comment: To find your "special chars", it depends on what you consider special. But comparing its value to a certain value is a good start

Comment: You are aware, of course, that this is not the way you write Unicode code points? That would be `U+00E8`. Also, why are you doing this? How is the other end supposed to decode it? And how are you going to handle code points outside the BMP?

Comment: This is my requirement: "è" (unicode U+00E8) to "\E8", I know this is not a standard escape but it is for ZPL printer language.

Comment: Special chars I supposed to be the ascii code>127, in other words, everything outside the standard ascii. May I use a regex to find it or a loop for every char of the string?

Answer (score 0):

> I have two problem:
>
> 1) How to find "special chars", may I check for each char value if it is >127?

That depends what your definition of "special" character is.  Testing for characters greater than 127 is testing for non-ASCII characters.  It is up to you to decide if that is what you want.

> 2) And how to get hex value as string.

The `Integer.toHexString` method can be used for that .

> 3) May I use a regex to find it or a loop for every char of the string?

A loop is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying this solution with a regex replacement (I don't know if it is better to loop for each char in string or to use the regex...)

```
                String test="This is a string with the special è unicode char";          
                Pattern pat=Pattern.compile("([^\\x20-\\x7E])");            
                int offset=0;           
                Matcher m=pat.matcher(test);            
                while(!m.hitEnd()) {
                    if (m.find(offset)) {
                        out.append(test.substring(offset,m.start()));               
                        for(int i=0;i<m.group(1).length();i++){
                          out.append(ESCAPE_CHAR);  
                          out.append(Integer.toHexString(m.group(1).charAt(i)).toUpperCase());
                        }                                           
                        offset=m.end();
                    }

                }
                return out.toString();
```

Comment: I'm posting this solution just to answer the haughty comment "We will not code it for you". That was not my request, I would just to know if there is a smarter way to escape a string, or something already done such as a method in StringUtils

Answer (score 0):

If your unicode characters are all in the range \u0080 - \u00FF you might use this solution.

```
public class Convert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String in = "This is a string with the special è unicode char";
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length());

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
            char charAt = in.charAt(i);
            if (charAt > 127) {
                // if there is a high number (several e.g. 100.000) of conversions
                // this lead in less objects to be garbadge collected
                out.append('\\').append(Integer.toHexString(charAt).toUpperCase());
                // out.append(String.format("\\%X", (int) charAt));
            } else {
                out.append(charAt);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
```