# How to Convert String to 0x hex format in Java?

Tags: java, string, hex

I can convert a string into hex format using *Javascript*, but I don't know how to do it in *Java*.

**For example:**

Given a string `Hello World` which to convert into hex fromat like `0x00 0x01 0x02 0x02 ...`

In *Javascript* I do the following:

```
var data = new Uint8Array(24);
for (var i = 0; i < 24 ; i++) {
            data[i] = "0x"+(string.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
        }
```

How do I convert a string into hex format in *Java*?

Comment: If there's a `printf()` method then this is great: `printf("0x%02X", number);`

Comment: Have you seen this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-alphabetical-character-to-hexadecimal-number-in-java> question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert a char from alphabetical character to hexadecimal number in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-alphabetical-character-to-hexadecimal-number-in-java)

Comment: A string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units. When you say "convert a string to hex format" what do you mean? "\u1234" ? 0x1234? 0x12 0x34? 0x34 0x12? [U+1234](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1234/index.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function receives asci String and convert it to hex String:

```
private static String asciiToHex(String asciiValue){
    char[] chars = asciiValue.toCharArray();
    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
        hex.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/string-class/convert-hex-to-ascii-and-ascii-to-hex/

Comment: No need to call `toCharArray()` — just use `asciiValue.length()` and `asciiValue.charAt(i)`.  That way you avoid making an unnecessary temporary copy of the string.