# How to get hex out of the string?

Tags: java, charset

I am reading a text file in Java line by line. For debugging purpose, I would like to get the hex value of the string to check how it is encoded.

For example:

This is my text-file:

```
äpple
tree
```

This is how I read the file:

```
inputCharset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fi), inputCharset));
while ( in.ready() ) {
      String row = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(row + " = " + toHex(row));
}
```

The result must be for first line

```
äpple = E4 70 70 6C 65
```

How can I convert the chars of the string to the appropriate hex value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a char from an alphabetical character to a hexadecimal number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477714/how-to-convert-a-char-from-an-alphabetical-character-to-a-hexadecimal-number-in)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting A String To Hexadecimal In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923863/converting-a-string-to-hexadecimal-in-java)

Comment: If you want the original byte values in the text file, you should use an `InputStream`, not a `Reader`. The problem with using a reader is that it will have already applied some transformation. If your file contained byte combinations not valid in ISO 8859-1 (though in practice that is no longer possible with that character set, for others it might be a valid concern), they would be transformed to a `?` or the Unicode replacement character. You can then no longer obtain the original byte value it had in the file.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's good advice, but how do you read one line at a time into a byte array using just an InputStream?

Comment: @k314159 You'd need to scan for end-of-line markers yourself. That is the trade-off here: either you want the original bytes, or you want to read as string, you can't have both (or at least, not always).

Comment: Edit to make clear whether you are trying to examine the octets in your file as stored, or whether you want to see how Java represents the text in memory (the code points).

Answer (score 2):

Since you have already read the line as a string, the easiest way should be to use [`String.codePoints()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePoints()) to get an `IntStream`.

```
String hexedRow = row.codePoints()
  .mapToObj(Integer::toHexString)
  .map(String::toUpperCase)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(row + " = " + hexedRow);
```

For `äpple` prints:

```
äpple = E4 70 70 6C 65
```

If you are not yet on java 9, you can simply iterate the characters and cast them to int before 'hex'-ing them.

Comment: This is not a general solution, as it will not necessarily result in the original bytes from the file. The hex-encoding of the codepoint value does not necessarily correspond to the hex-encoding of the original underlying bytes in the text file. In fact, this will basically only work for iso-8859-1 (except maybe some of the control codes). For any other character set that maps any byte 0-255 to anything other than U+0000 - U+00FF it will produce the wrong result.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The Question is not clear. The title asks: “How to get hex out of the string?”. This Answer addresses that.

Comment: @BasilBourque The question says _"I would like to get the hex value of the string to check how it is encoded"_, there is only one place where the string is encoded, and that is in the file. Printing the codepoints is not the way to go about it if that is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

For something with good flexibility, you can use the new [`HexFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html) class introduced in Java 17:

```
var inputCharset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;
var hexFormat = HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").withUpperCase();
try (var in = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(fi), inputCharset))) {
    String row;
    while ((row = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(row + " = " + hexFormat.formatHex(row.getBytes(inputCharset));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the binary representation of the string, you use the `getBytes` method on the string:

```java
byte[] bytes = row.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Once you have a raw byte array, there are [various ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/java-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string) to display it as a hex string.