# Java a program that accepts a hexadecimal representation of a number and outputs the decimal representation of that number

Tags: java

I got a program to convert integer to Hexadecimal, but I want the input to be Hexadecimal and convert to decimal. Please help....

```
 int m; String Hdec="";
   while(m>0){
int rem;
rem=m%16;
if(rem>=0&rem<=9)
Hdec=rem+Hdec;
else if(rem==10)
    Hdec="A"+Hdec;
else if(rem==11)
    Hdec="B"+Hdec;
else if(rem==12)
    Hdec="C"+Hdec;
else if(rem==13)
            Hdec="D"+Hdec;
else if(rem==14)
    Hdec="D"+Hdec;
else if(rem==15)
    Hdec="D"+Hdec;
m=m/16;
     }
     sop(Hdec);
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: there is no problem with the above code, but I want to convert hexadecimal to decimal

Comment: `int i = Integer.parseInt(someNumber, 16);` found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338193/convert-hexadecimal-number-to-decimal). It was the second link on a google search.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody already implemented this, you can use for example

```
Integer.parseInt("1a", 16)
```

and will get the result 26.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HexDec {

private static final int DECIMAL = 10;
private static final int HEXADECIMAL = 16;

public HexDec() {
    BigInteger hexNumber = new BigInteger(fetchInput(), HEXADECIMAL);

    System.out.println("Number in Decimal: " + hexNumber.toString(DECIMAL));
}

private String fetchInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
    String input = scanner.next();
    scanner.close();

    return input;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new HexDec();
}
}
```

The above program can take even big hexadecimal integers and print their decimal integer representation even if it exceeds the limit of int and long variables.